# Error in using typedef

Tags: c

I have this code in c-

This is my `Room.h` file

```
typedef int Room[10][10];
```

THis is my main code-

```
#include"Room.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


    int createRoom(Room * pm,char *filename)
     {

       FILE * input;FILE * output;

       input=fopen(filename,"r");

        int a;int i=0,j=0;int count;    
        fscanf(input,"%d",&a);
        while(!feof(input))
         {
            pm[i][j]=a;    // incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[10]’ from type ‘int’

            i++;j++;count++;
            fscanf (input, "%d", &a);
         }
        for(i=0;i<count;i++)
          {
            for(j=0;j<count;j++)
               printf("%d  ",pm[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
          }
         fclose(input);
        return count;
     }

    int main()
     {

       char name[100];
       printf("Enter file name\n");
       scanf("%s",name);
       Room *pm;
       //pm=malloc(sizeof(Maze ));
       int n=createRoom(pm,name);
       return 0;
     }
```

I get this error- `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[10]’ from type ‘int’` in this line-`pm[i][j]=a;` .Why is it so?

Comment: `Room *pm` is `int (*)[10][10]`, and I doubt you intended that. Just passing `Room pm` should get you closer. And `Room *pm;` down in main is equally one-level-too-deep on the indirection. Likewise change it to `Room pm;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
pm[i][j]=a;
```

needs to be changed to

```
(*pm)[i][j]=a;
```

More importantly, your code does not allocate memory for `pm`. In `main`, you have:

```
Room *pm;
//pm=malloc(sizeof(Maze ));
int n=createRoom(pm,name);
```

I wonder why you removed the line to allocate memory for `pm`. You can use:

```
Room *pm;
pm=malloc(sizeof(*pm));
int n=createRoom(pm,name);
```

and make sure to deallocate memory.

```
free(pm);
```

Or, you could just use:

```
Room pm;
int n=createRoom(&pm,name);
```